# Problema ao tentar baixar arquivos grandes

Tags: php, download

Estou usando este código para fazer o download com php, arquivos pequenos funciona, agora grandes como de 1Gb acabam vindo corrompidos.

```
$arquivo = $_GET['nome']; //nome do Arquivo
$local = $_GET['dir']; //pasta onde está o arquivo

header('Cache-control: private');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($local.$arquivo));
header('Content-Disposition: filename='.$arquivo);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($local.$arquivo));

//envia o download
readfile($local.$arquivo);

<a href="download?nome=arquivo.ext&dir=pasta/">Download</a>
```

Comment: Seu servidor é apache?

Comment: sim, php 7 .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção é usar o **[x-sendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/)** . Antes de mais nada você precisa ter `mod_xsendfile` no módulo do servidor. Se você não tiver, o link acima tem uma área para download.

Depois você precisa configura-lo no seu arquivo `httpd.conf` adicionando isso:

```
XSendFile on // <-- ligou a criança
XSendFilePath /path/to/files/directory // <-- diretório dos arquivos que estão liberados para serem acessados
```

E então você conseguirá usa-lo:

```
header("X-Sendfile: $arquivo"); // <--- aqui está!
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($local.$arquivo));
```

Eu usei apenas uma vez e funcionou com um arquivo bem grande!

Aqui tem um **[exemplo no GitHub](https://gist.github.com/chrisbloom7/854168)**